# Adding address marker to this Google Map API V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have this map working fine, i just wanted to add the default google click address marker and if not that a custom bubble for the address?

Anyone help me out, i'm sure its simple but cannot figure out whereabouts to put it..?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

   var map;

   jQuery(function($) {
       $(document).ready(function() {
           var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
           var myOptions = {
               zoom: 8,
               center: latlng,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
           console.dir(map);
           google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

           $('a[href="#tab2"]').on('shown', function(e) {
               google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
           });
       });



   });
```

Many thanks..

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out..

Anyone who needs a marker and for it to work with jQuery tabs try this..

```
               function initialize() {


                         var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
                         var mapOptions = {
                           zoom: 4,
                           center: myLatlng,
                           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                         }
                         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), mapOptions);

                         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                             position: myLatlng,
                             map: map,
                             title: 'Hello World!'
                         });


                       }

                       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```